# Deal unpickled arguments in Python

Tags: python, pickle

Using the multiprocessing library in Python, we pickle objects behind the scene to let the other process a background of what objects they should hold.
Some objects like files are "unpickleable" and need special treatment.
In the following example, I used the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` to operate when my class `Person` is pickled.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name: str, age: float):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pow_func = lambda number: number * number
        self.file = open(f'{name}_{age}_file', 'w')

    def write_to_file(self, message: str):
        self.file.write(message)

    # When this isn't implemented, pickle try to serialize class.<locals> AKA __dict__
    # If this function returns false, the function __setstate__ won't be called when unpickling
    def __getstate__(self):
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        temp = open('temp', 'wb')
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            try:
                pickle.dump(value, temp)
            except Exception:
                print(f'Cant pickle {key}, we need special treatment')
                state.update({str(key) + '_pickle_change': str(value)})
                del state[key]
        return state

    # This function responsible for the unpickling
    def __setstate__(self, state: dict):
        for key, value in state.items():
            if '_pickle_change' not in key:
                self.__dict__.update({key: value})
            else:
                print(f'Bad type: {key}, {value}')
                # What should we do here?
                pass
```

As you can read, I add _pickle_change to its name for every unpickle object and the str of its value.
My question is, What should I do in `__setstate__`to recall the file and lambda functions as I did in **init**? How do I make sure it will be generic?

Comment: If it were that simple to pickle non-pickleable objects, they would just be pickleable in the first place. What you're looking for isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

For the above example you could use `ast` to grab the file opener as string and later at setstate eval it back again. For lambdas there are plenty of thing one could to. You may use lambdser or dill. A in more generic way would be to register you own pickler.

A more simpler approach would be to use pathos mp which uses dill under the hood.

```py
import dill


class Person:

    def __init__(self, name: str, age: float):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.pow_func = lambda number: number * number
        self.file = open(f'{name}_{age}_file', 'w')

    def write_to_file(self, message: str):
        self.file.write(message)
        
assert dill.dumps(Person("seimen", 42))
```